# With PHP Curl, I want to scrape H1s into a database

Tags: php, curl

I want to scrape a website, let's say CNN, every hour and add any titles in an H1 into a new row into my MYSQL table. How do I do that?

Comment: I'll do this for you for $200.

Comment: What's your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: You might want to dig through Google, learn a bit, and come back when you have specific questions about specific issues. You can start by searching Google for "php curl tutorial", then "parse html with php", and finally "php mysql tutorial". Put those skills together to solve all but the *hourly* bit, which is probably best suited for [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 3):

I don't expect anyone to do the whole work for you, but here's something to get you started.

First of all, you need to get the actual source, you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or [curl](http://php.net/curl) for this. There's plenty on information about how around here.

Then you need to scrape CNN for all H1-tags. A simple way to do this is to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument). Here is a simple function to get all headings from a HTML source:

```
function get_h1($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html); // Supress warnings if our html is not well formed
    $headings = $dom->getElementsByTagName("h1");

    $retval = array();

    foreach($headings as $header) {
        $retval[] = $header->nodeValue;
    }

    return $retval;
}
```

Note that this does not account for different encodings etc.

Another option for parsing is to use the excellent [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

You then need to save it into your database, you can use the [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) libraries for this.

Lastly, you need to run this hourly. Do this using a cron-jobs. You can find information about how to set up your cron jobs [here](http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/).

This should help to get you started. You probably want to add some more features to this, like ensuring your not adding duplicate headings etc.

Comment: Nir Levy is lucky to have you around, alexn :) Hope he sticks around long enough to award you with a green check mark.

Comment: Nir Levy should send you $200.

Answer (score 0):

You know, this has me curious.  I was just playing around with NodeJS.  I bet server-side JQuery and AJAX could really knock something like this out in a flash.  Not sure about connecting to the database though, but the parsing would be a cake walk.

Comment: From my experience, excluding bugs, it's pretty RAM/CPU heavy to do decent-sized scrape jobs in Node. I've found PHP + regex to be the best bet for simple scraping/parsing.

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks for passing that on.